# Apache Cayenne insert data from a non cayenne app to database

Tags: apache-cayenne

I've an Tomcat app running with cayenne, now I habe another application that inserts/changes data from outside in the db! As cayenne is fully cached, what would be the best way to make cayenne aware of the new / changed rows?

regards
Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're using Query caches, any explicit fetch (e.g. a [SelectQuery](https://cayenne.apache.org/docs/4.1/api/org/apache/cayenne/query/SelectQuery.html)) you do in Cayenne will still hit the database, and thus should find the changed content.